# How to access Google Search "I'm Feeling Lucky" functionality using API?

Tags: api, google-search, google-search-api

I'm creating a sample app that will take a query from user and will return the URL result returned from Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" search. Does Google expose this functionality through their API? How to access this?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Google change their `I'm feeling lucky` url.

A workaround is to use `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+github+foo+bar+foobar`

`https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ducky+YOUR_URL_ENCODED_QUERY`

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing magic about Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" functionality.  It simply picks the first result of the search.  So, however you're using the api, you can just select the first result as well.

Furthermore, you can use this format for a URL in order to hit the "I'm Feeling Lucky" result of Google:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=my+keywords+for+search&btnI
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 'btnI' is not working already, at least, for me. Correction: it works for some simple queries (term, term+term), but doesn't for some others (tsql+like).

Comment: See https://travishorn.com/link-directly-to-googles-i-m-feeling-lucky-feature-65ebe7b552bd

Answer (score 1):

*Deprecated* <strike>You could use the Google API which is probably the best way to do it but will require more work
api docs here https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/</strike>

*No longer working* <strike>or you can go to this url with your seach query:
http://www.google.com/webhp#q=your+search+query+here&btnI</strike>

be sure you add &btnI to the end otherwise it wont redirect

---

**Update 2014**

The above URL stopped working and yes the search API is depreciated, however there are always workaround. If you really have to you can still use a simple get request on the following URL:

https://www.google.com/search?q=your+search+query+here&btnI=

with of course `your+search+query+here` replaced with a URL encoded string.

Comment: This no longer works. Google now check the refferer header.