# Link directly to the first Google search result

Tags: google-search

I want to link directly to **the first Google search result**, is it possible?
I would be using a **very** specific search query, including `site:specificsite.example`. Like a direct-link to the "I'm feeling lucky"-button.

**Example:** `https://www.google.no/search?q=how+do+i+get+a+facebook+pixel+site%3Afacebook.com`

From the top of my head, I'd think either a PHP curl request to either Google API or to the normal Google search site, and then echoing the first result as a link. OR doing the same, but with AJAX.

**But I'm guessing there must be a more straight forward way?**

PS: I don't want a discussion about if it's a good idea or not, just if it's possible or not, and maybe a hint on how to do it most simple.

Comment: Should this already be listed in Google API documentation? /// What a comment section... (below)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657548/is-it-ok-to-scrape-data-from-google-results/22703153#22703153 something useful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5506561

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877882/how-to-access-google-search-im-feeling-lucky-functionality-using-api?rq=1

Comment: basically we have no direct answer this is just scattered everywhere lol

Comment: Thanks. 1. Looks like there WAS a way using a parameter to trigger the "Feeling lucky"-button, but it's gone. 2. Also the open google search api is deprecated, so a simple api request without the hassle of registering first is also gone. 3. I'm left with using either my self-made php scraper or someones else. :)